# Как найти евклидово растояние двух матриц?

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, numpy, линейная-алгебра

Есть numpy array `X`, размерностью `(num_test, D)`, где `D` - матрица некоторого размера. Есть numpy array `X_train`, размерностью `(num_train, D)`.

Нужно найти Евклидово расстояние между каждой матрицей в `X` и между каждой матрицей в `X_train`. Не используя циклов и используя только базовые операции над матрицами. Нельзя использовать библиотеку `scipy` и `np.linalg.norm()`.

То есть, нужно заполнить numpy array размерностью `(num_test, num_train)`, где каждая запись это расстояние между i-той матрией из `X` и j-ой матрицей из `X_train`.

До этого нужно было написать тоже самое, но используя два цикла:

```
def compute_distances_two_loops(self, X):
        """
        Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
        in self.X_train using a nested loop over both the training data and the
        test data.

        Inputs:
        - X: A numpy array of shape (num_test, D) containing test data.

        Returns:
        - dists: A numpy array of shape (num_test, num_train) where dists[i, j]
          is the Euclidean distance between the ith test point and the jth training
          point.
        """
        num_test = X.shape[0]
        num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
        dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
        for i in range(num_test):
            for j in range(num_train):
                #####################################################################
                # TODO:                                                             #
                # Compute the l2 distance between the ith test point and the jth    #
                # training point, and store the result in dists[i, j]. You should   #
                # not use a loop over dimension, nor use np.linalg.norm().          #
                #####################################################################
                # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

                dists[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((X[i] - self.X_train[j])**2))

                # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****
        return dists
```

И один цикл:

```
def compute_distances_one_loop(self, X):
        """
        Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
        in self.X_train using a single loop over the test data.

        Input / Output: Same as compute_distances_two_loops
        """
        num_test = X.shape[0]
        num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
        dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
        for i in range(num_test):
            #######################################################################
            # TODO:                                                               #
            # Compute the l2 distance between the ith test point and all training #
            # points, and store the result in dists[i, :].                        #
            # Do not use np.linalg.norm().                                        #
            #######################################################################
            # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

            dists[i, :] = np.sqrt(np.sum((X[i] - self.X_train)**2, axis=1))

            # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****
        return dists
```

Как сделать тоже самое но не используя циклов, у меня дойти не получается.

Если что это домашка из Стэнфордского курса по компьютерному зрению. Я не пытаюсь сжульничить в настоящей домашке, за которую ставят оценки. Просто пытась понять, как это сделать. Поэтому, будет ещё лучше если вы объясните с точки зрения математики, что вы делаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение, подсмотренное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359192/5741205):

```
def dist_pairwise(a, b):
    P = np.add.outer(np.sum(a**2, axis=1), np.sum(b**2, axis=1))
    N = np.dot(a, b.T)
    return np.sqrt(P - 2*N)
```

---

Примеры:

```
In [196]: a = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))

In [197]: b = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 3))

In [198]: a
Out[198]:
array([[3, 5, 0],
       [2, 6, 2],
       [4, 4, 6],
       [3, 0, 6],
       [4, 7, 6]])

In [199]: b
Out[199]:
array([[7, 1, 5],
       [7, 9, 2],
       [4, 8, 1],
       [2, 1, 1]])

In [200]: dists = dist_pairwise(a, b)

In [201]: dists
Out[201]:
array([[ 7.54983444,  6.        ,  3.31662479,  4.24264069],
       [ 7.68114575,  5.83095189,  3.        ,  5.09901951],
       [ 4.35889894,  7.07106781,  6.40312424,  6.164414  ],
       [ 4.24264069, 10.63014581,  9.48683298,  5.19615242],
       [ 6.78232998,  5.38516481,  5.09901951,  8.06225775]])

In [202]: dists.shape
Out[202]: (5, 4)
```

Проверка для первой строки:

```
In [210]: np.linalg.norm(a[0] - b[0])
Out[210]: 7.54983443527075

In [211]: np.linalg.norm(a[0] - b[1])
Out[211]: 6.0

In [212]: np.linalg.norm(a[0] - b[2])
Out[212]: 3.3166247903554

In [213]: np.linalg.norm(a[0] - b[3])
Out[213]: 4.242640687119285
```

---

**Пояснение формулы:**

Чтобы понять как работает это решение можно рассмотреть тривиальный случай расчета расстояния между двумя точками [`A(x1, y1)` и `B(x2, y2)`] в двумерном пространстве:

Евклидово расстояние между точками A и B:

```
dist = sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
```

если раскрыть скобки внутри функции `sqrt(...)` то получится:

```
x2**2 - 2*x2*x1 + x1**2 + y2**2 - 2*y2*y1 + y1**2
```

или, упростив:

```
(x1**2 + x2**2 + y1**2 + y2**2 - 2*(x1*x2 + y1*y2))
```